# How to display the filter text from the tabel list?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a text filter with a table list, in these when we write any of the text in the text field then it filter out from the list and display.
Now, what I want is when I write the text in the text field then it filter out from the list and displayed. For this I have applied implicitlyWait so that the page can wait for a moment until it filter or load the page but it didn't work.
Below are code and the snapshot of the table on which I am performing a test.

[image]

```
WebElement usUserName = driver.findElement(By.id("gs_UserName"));
                usUserName.sendKeys("admin");
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: So here, soon after you enter "admin" it filters out? or do you need to click on "Find" or any button? If there is no button as such, after entering the text, try click Tab or something then the filter may happen.

Comment: @Uday when I write the text in the field then it filters out from the table list without any click event via button button or enter through keyboard.

Comment: what happens if you make it sleep for 2sec before entering admin? It might be filled in to quickly so it doesn't filter.

Comment: @Decypher I just write the text admin and wait that the user filters out but its not filter out and driver has been closed.

Comment: @user2092132 do you have an example of this somewhere?